# Efficient way to search several SQlite db's in Python for particular string in set of columns?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Context: I am currently writing a search feature for a series of sqlite3 databases in python and am wondering if the following functionality is possible in python 3.7 with sqlite3.

I have three databases (Equipment, Tools, Landscape)

Every table in these three databases has the exact same schema, being:
(form_id (KEY), name, item, purpose, cost, serial, date, attach, notes)

The goal is to have a user on the front end type a string into a search field, press enter, and the string they typed will be passed to this function in the backend, which will compare it to a set of specific columns.

my psuedo code for searching the databases for a given string on a defined set of columns looks like:

#### def search(search_str, database):

1. Loop through each database (There are 3 total)
2. Loop through each table in the open database
3. SELECT form_id, name, item, serial, notes FROM table WHERE name, item, serial or note is like %search_str%
4. If found, append (form_id, name, item, serial, note) to a dictionary

continue...

I have the following code:

```
def search_index(search_str, databases):
json_str = []

for database in databases:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    c = conn.cursor()
    for tablerow in c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence'").fetchall():
        table = tablerow[0]
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(table))
        for row in c:
            print(row)
            for field in row.keys():
                #Here I would append the appropriate data
                json_str.append(field)
     conn.close()
return json_str
```

So far the second execute query:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(table))
```

Will not accept any column names as I figure they are out of scope since the table argument is iterated through and not known until runtime.

Is this how I should be approaching this problem? I feel like there is an easier way to search all of my databases for a particular string that doesn't involve an O(N) search. Any advice or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds as if using [FTS](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) might be a better solution.